# Improvement of Chernoff bound in Binomial case

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities

We know from Chernoff bound
$P\bigg(X \leq (\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)N\bigg)\leq e^{-2\epsilon^2 N}$ where 
$X$ follows Binomial($N, \frac{1}{2}$).

If I take $N=1000, \epsilon=0.01$, the upper bound is 0.82. 
However, the actual value is 0.27. Can we improve this Chernoff bound?

Comment: A source for this bound is Corollary 4.10 in the book of Mitzenmacher and Upfal

Comment: The large deviation bound is useful for $\epsilon$ fixed and $N$ very large. When $\epsilon \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$ one should use the central limit theorem (which gives an equality).

Answer (score 7):

An explicit high-accuracy bound on the Kolmogorov distance between a properly standardized binomial distribution $B(N,p)$ and the standard normal distribution is provided by the theorem on page 129 of Uspensky's book "Introduction to Mathematical Probability" (1937). In your case, of $p=1/2$, this theorem implies that for any integer $x$ and any natural $N\ge100$ 
\begin{equation}
 |P(X\le x)-\Phi(z)|<\delta:=\frac{0.52}N+\exp(-\tfrac34\,\sqrt N),
\end{equation}
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cumulative distribution function and $z:=(x-Np+1/2)/\sqrt{N/4}$. In particular, for your $N=1000$, we have $\delta=0.000520000050\ldots<\frac1{1923}$. So, for $N=1000, \epsilon=0.01$, Uspensky's result implies that the true probability (which is $0.27398\ldots$) is in the interval $[0.27397\ldots-\frac1{1923},0.27397\ldots+\frac1{1923}]\subset[0.27345, 0.27450]$, which is much more informative than 
the Chernoff and entropy upper bounds on $0.27398\ldots$, which both are $\approx0.82$.

As was commented by user RaphaelB4, the Chernoff and entropy upper bounds are bounds on probabilities of large deviations. Those probabilities are small, in contrast with your probability $0.27398\ldots$, which makes large deviation bounds unsuitable in your example. Also, there are large deviation bounds much better than Chernoff's. E.g., in a more general situation one has an upper bound on large deviation probabilities that is [asymptotic to the corresponding Gaussian tail](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ejp/1465062357).

Comment: This feels like the "right" answer; we are in a regime where the central limit theorem approximation ought to be good.  Also, if you want something more explicit, the Taylor polynomial for $\Phi$ is easy to use here.  Looks to me like 7th order gets you a comparable error bound.

Comment: @NateEldredge : Thank you for your comment. However, I did not understand the part of it concerning the Taylor polynomial for $\Phi$ -- how do I use it to bound the binomial tail? Did you mean the Edgeworth expansion for the binomial distribution? If so, I don't know explicit bounds on the error of the Edgeworth expansion.

Comment: All I mean is this trivial comment: you can take an appropriate Taylor polynomial for $\Phi$, call it $p_7$, and use your favorite remainder bound to estimate $|\Phi(z) - p_7(z)|$.  Then the triangle inequality gives you bounds on $|P(X\le x) - p_7(z)|$ and you get upper and lower bounds on $P(X \le x)$ that are completely closed-form.

Comment: @NateEldredge : Oh, I see now. I did not envision any problem working with $\Phi$. It has many kinds of however good approximations by what is traditionally called elementary functions. As for analytical properties of $\Phi$, I think they are no less convenient to deal with than those of trig functions or power functions with a fractional exponent (say), even though the latter are considered closed form; indeed, the derivative of $\Phi$ is a composition of a quadratic function and the exponential function -- both easy to deal with.

Answer (score 6):

One can obtain a slight improvment using an entropy bound. It is well known that
$$\sum_{i \le m} \binom{N}{i} \le 2^{N \cdot H(m/N)},$$
where $m\le N/2$ and $H$ is the binary entropy function. Thus,
$$P(X \le (\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)N) = 2^{-N}\sum_{i \le (\frac{1}{2}-\varepsilon)N} \binom{N}{i} \le 2^{N(-1+H(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon))}.$$

This is *always* superior to the Chernoff bound. In fact, a Taylor expansion of $H$ around $\frac{1}{2}$ shows that

$$H(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)=1-\frac{1}{2\log 2} \sum_{n \ge 1}\frac{(2\epsilon)^{2n}}{n(2n-1)},$$
so that
$$ P(X \le (\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon)N) \le e^{-N(2\epsilon^2 +\sum_{n \ge 2}\frac{(2\epsilon)^{2n}}{2n(2n-1)})}.$$
For you numbers ($N=10^3, p=10^{-2}$), I get 0.818...

Answer (score 3):

Section 1.3 of the book *Random Graphs* by Bela Bollobas gives tighter bounds on tail probabilities of the binomial distribution by using the normal distribution. For instance, the top of page 12 discusses the entropy bound Ofir mentioned. Theorems 1.6-1.7 on pages 13-14 go further, using the DeMoivre-Laplace theorem. The probability you are looking at is approximately $\frac{1}{x \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ where $x = \epsilon N / \sqrt{.25 N}$. Bollobas then says

> the best bounds to date (which are essentially best possible) are due to Littlewood (1969), whose paper is highly recommended

Sounds like it would be a good exercise to see what the Littlewood bound says in your case. The reference is "On the probability in the tail of a binomial distribution", *Adv. Appl. Probab.* 1, 43-72

Answer (score 1):

Actually the Littlewood bound had an error which was corrected by McKay:

Brendan D. McKay, On Littlewood's Estimate for the Binomial Distribution, *Advances in Applied Probability*, Vol. 21, No. 2 (Jun., 1989), pp. 475-478.